# What are the projects building EVM compatible chains on Solana apart from Neon Labs?

Tags: solana-program, ethereum, neon-evm

I have been trying to find projects bringing EVM compatibility to Solana, and so far have only found Neon Labs doing so. My question is if there are any other projects trying to do the same? Or is Neon Labs the only one?

Answer (score 3):

Solang is the other big project, but it's a compiler for Solidity rather than an EVM on-chain.

You can learn more about the project at https://solang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/targets/solana.html